# Can I lock a collection in the get accessor?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I have a lightly used dictionary which is hardly ever going to be read or updated since the individual items raise events and return their results with their event args. In fact the thread is always going to be updated with the same thread. I was thinking about adding a simple lock just to be safe. I was wondering if I can just place the lock in the get accessor. Does this work?

```
        Dictionary<string,Indicator> indicators = new Dictionary<string,Indicator>();
        Dictionary<string, Indicator> Indicators
        {
            get
            {
                lock (indicators)
                {
                    return indicators;
                }
            }
        }

        public void AddIndicator(Indicator i)
        {
            lock (indicators)
            {
                indicators.Add(i.Name, i);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That doesn't do anything particularly useful, no.

In particular, if you have:

```
x = foo.Indicators["blah"]
```

then the indexer will be executed *without* the thread holding the lock... so it's not thread-safe. Think of the above code like this:

```
Dictionary<string, Indicator> indicators = foo.Indicators;
// By now, your property getter has completed, and the lock has been released...
x = indicators["blah"];
```

Do you ever need to do anything with the collection other than access it via the indexer? If not, you might want to just replace the property with a method:

```
public Indicator GetIndicator(string name)
{
    lock (indicators)
    {
        return indicators[name];
    }
}
```

(You may want to use `TryGetValue` instead, etc - it depends on what you're trying to achieve.)

Personally I'd prefer to use a reference to a privately-owned-and-otherwise-unused lock object rather than locking on the collection reference, but that's a separate matter.

As mentioned elsewhere, `ConcurrentDictionary` is your friend *if* you're using .NET 4, but of course it's not available prior to that :(

Answer (score 4):

Other than Jon's input, I'll say don't lock the collection `indicators` itself anyway, from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1c9txz50.aspx):

> Use caution when locking on instances,
>   for example lock(this) in C# or
>   SyncLock(Me) in Visual Basic. If other
>   code in your application, external to
>   the type, takes a lock on the object,
>   deadlocks could occur.

It is recommended to use a dedicated `object` instance to lock onto. There are other places where this is covered with more details and reasons why - even here on SO, should you care to search for the information when you have time.

Comment: I was just adding something similar to my own answer :)

Comment: @Jon: Certainly didn't think you would fall short in providing good coverage - just sticking my own neck out a bit!

Comment: I wasn't trying to condemn your answer at all - just remarking on the coincidence of timing :)

Comment: @Jon: I didn't think so. And I just realised what an exclamation mark might seem to imply as opposed to, or when not accompanied by a smiley... I should have used this, too: :)

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, you could use [ConcurrentDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx) which handles the thread safety for you.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: YES.
Why shouldn't that work, but as mention by Jon, it does not lock as intended when using indexes?

Comment: It's not "array access" - it's an indexer. But more importantly the lock will have been released by the time you get the reference back *whatever you then do with it*.

Comment: @jon: Thanks for the hint, I'm programming PHP at the moment ther it is called array access...